# PHP include HTML menu

Tags: php, html, include

I have search this a lot and have seen a few questions on here but have not found my answer.  I guess this is the worst kind of question because it's one of this annoying situations where the code looks fine, debug's without error but will not render the desired result in a browser.  I am new to PHP but this is just a simple "include" script which should work according to a hand full of sites that I have checked.  I am trying to include a simple menu into each page with PHP.

Code snippet I have in my index html page:

```
<div id="menuContainer"><?php include "menu.php" ?>
</div>
```

The file I am trying to include is in file "menu.php" and includes text:

```
<nav>
    <menu class='menu'>
        <menuitem id='home'>
            <a href='index.html' class='homeButton'>Home</a>
            <label>|</label>
        </menuitem>
        <menuitem>
            <a href='#' class='bioButton'>Bio</a>
            <label>|</label>
        </menuitem>
        <menuitem>
            <a href='underthehood.html' class='hoodButton'>Under the hood</a>
            <label>|</label>
        </menuitem>
        <menuitem>
            <a href='#' class='contactButton'>Contact</a>
        </menuitem>
    </menu>
</nav>
```

Pages are live on a server that supports PHP so i am out of ideas.  Also I have debugged in vs.code and no errors.

Comment: Nothing is displayed at all ? No errors messages ?

Comment: try `include("menu.php");` you should always end your functions with `;`

Comment: you are trying to use php in `.html` file. That won't work

Comment: your first page is index.php and not index.html, right?

Comment: change include to `require_once`. You'll get an error if it is in the wrong folder and can't find it, in which case you'll be able to sort it

Comment: Thanks to all for taking the time to comment on my post;  I have just had time to look at them.  Ezhno - Yes that's correct no menu visually and no error both in vb.code and when browser renders the page.  I tried include("menu.php"); as you suggested but still no result.  ArtOsi - are you sure?  i checked online and seems you can use <? PHP  ?> on a .html page unless i am wrong which is always possible :)  check out <https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_includes.asp.  I also tried require_once but still no error or menu.  I have a feeling it's something very minor that will make me look foolish!

Comment: I should also state that menu.php file is in the same directory as the index.html so path "menu.php" should find the file to my mind

Comment: Another example online of PHP being used in a html page https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/scripting-and-programming/php/php-in/